# Prove that$ A \subseteq B$ where $A = \{ x \in Z \vert \ x\equiv 4\pmod 9 \}\ $ and $\ B = \{ x \in Z \vert \ x\equiv 1\pmod 3 \}$

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

I am really confused that how can I demonstrate please help me to explain this

Prove that$ A \subseteq B$ where
$A = \{ x \in Z \vert \ x\equiv 4\pmod 9 \}\ $ and
$\ B = \{ x \in Z \vert \ x\equiv 1\pmod 3 \}$.

How it is possible to demonstrate that $A$ is a subset of $B$ ?

Comment: An element of $A$ is of the form $(9x+4) = 3(3x+1) + 1$, so  leaves a remainder of $1$ when divided by $3$, hence the element is in $B$.

Comment: so any number divisible by 9 is also by 3?

Comment: Yes. If you do not mind, may I ask which class you are in? Because I think the congruence notation is taught way after basic arithmetic, which is covered in 6th grade.

Comment: I am in year 9 but I mentioned that question as I want to know exactly the opposite of what I posted Prove that A is not a subset B where A = { x ∈ Z | x ≡ 4 (mod 9) } and B = { x ∈ Z | x ≡ 1 (mod 3) }? Can you please explain me this ?

Comment: but then, as the answers show below, *$A$ is a subset of $B$*. And yes, anything that's divisible by nine is divisible by $3$. Ok, here's a tip for you: the minute you see something like: "a number is divisible by 9", or "a number divides 5040", quickly convert it into mathematical notation. For example, "$y$ is divisible by 9" translates to  $y=9x$ where $x$ is a number. Similarly, "$y$ divides 5040" translates to $yx=5040$, where $x$ is  a number. Now, if $9$ divides $y$, then $y=9x=3 * (3x)$, hence 3 divides $y$. You see how clearly the answer comes out? This approach is very helpful.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x \in A$. Then $x = 9n + 4$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

But then we can also write $x$ as $$x = 9n + 4 = 9n + 3 + 1 = 3(3n+1) + 1.$$
Now as $n$ is an integer, so too is $3n+1$, which we put $m$.

Thus, $$x = 3m+1,$$ where $m = 3n+1 \in \mathbb{Z}$. So $$x \cong 1 ( \mod 3),$$ showing that $x \in B$. Hence $A \subset B$.

Comment: but is there a way to prove that a is not a subset of b ?

Comment: We have proved that $A$ _is_ a subset of $B$. So now how can we prove that $A$ is _not_ a subset of $B$?

Answer (score 0):

Here we will show $A \subseteq B$ by inclusion. Let $a \in A$ be an arbitrary element. By the definition of modular arithmetic, we know since $x \equiv 4 \text{ (mod} \ 9)$ there must exist some integer $z_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 
$$x = 4 + 9z_1.$$
Notice that this implies 
$$x = 1 + 3 + 9z_1 = 1 + 3(1+3z_1).$$

Since the quantity $(1 + 3z_1)$ is an integer (being a linear combination of integers), and all integer multiples of 3 are equivalent to 0 modulo 3, it must be that
$$x \equiv 1 \text{ (mod} \ 3)$$

Comment: I mean to say that is there any value of x for which this statement is false Prove that A is not a subset  B where A = { x ∈ Z | x ≡ 4 (mod 9) } and B = { x ∈ Z | x ≡ 1 (mod 3) }?

Comment: $A$ is a proper subset of $B$. You can show this via counterexample (i.e. showing a member of $B$ who does not exist in $A$): $1$ is equivalent to $1$ mod $3$, so it is in $B$. However, it is not equivalent to $4$ modulo $9$, so $1 \notin A$. In fact, it is equivalent to $1$ mod $9$.

Comment: Gracias for everything